# How can I find out why PIL isn't drawing the font correctly?

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from PIL import Image
import ImageFont, ImageDraw
import sys
import pdb

img = Image.new("RGBA",(300,300))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype(sys.argv[1],30)
draw.text((0,100),"world",font=font,fill="red")
del draw
img.save(sys.argv[2],"PNG")
```

and here's the image that results:
[img http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?976a0d3eaa.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?976a0d3eaa.png) ( for some reason, I can't make it show on SO, so the link is http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?976a0d3eaa.png )

The thing is, I don't understand why it isn't drawing the font correctly? I should be able to read the word "world" off of it. It's like the picture's been cut in half or something. Does anyone have any clue?

EDIT: after balpha's comment, I decided to try another font. I'm only interested in ttf fonts, so I tried with another one, and it worked. This is kind of strange. The original font I tried to run this with is [Beautiful ES](http://www.fonts101.com/xt_fontdetails_az_FID!18928~Beautiful_ES~font.html). I'm curious if you guys can reproduce the same image on your computers, and if you happen to know the reason for why that is.

Comment: Works fine here -- have you tried different fonts?

Comment: Only tried with a TTF. I'll try others and post feedback.

Comment: I have tried Arial, Times, and Calibri Bold (all TrueType). All of them look fine.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on why Beautiful ES wasn't drawed correctly? It's not that I'm particularly fond of that font, it's just that it was the first one I tested with, and it would be useful to know if PIL reacts in a certain way to some type of fonts.

Comment: I have certainly reproduced your error, so it's probably an issue with the font. FontForge finds some problems within the font; it's definitely not a high quality one. There's a whole lot of things people can do wrong when creating fonts, and that might cause problems in one case and look fine in other cases (although I cannot explicitly say that it's not PIL's fault in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIL uses the freetype2 library, so most possibly it is an issue with the font file; for example, it could have bad metrics defined (e.g see the OS/2 related ones opening the font with FontForge).